# How to design resuable react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am using React for my project. Firstly, I need to design a resuable `Input` component. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
const Input = ({
  name,
  value,
  label,
  errorMessage,
  type,
  onChange,
  fullWidth
}) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      name={name}
      value={value}
      label={label}
      helperText={<span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorMessage}</span>}
      type={type}
      onChange={onChange}
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth={fullWidth}
    />
  );
};
```

For this component, I totally pass `seven` props. However, some of props like `name`, `type` and `fullWidth` they are more like a `config`. My question is that should I pass these props directly, or should I wrap these three props in an `others` props like this:

```
const Input = ({
  value,
  label,
  errorMessage,
  onChange,
  others
}) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={value}
      label={label}
      helperText={<span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorMessage}</span>}
      onChange={onChange}
      margin="normal"
      {...others}
    />
  );
};
```

It might make other developers more flexible to use this component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const DeliInput = ({
  value,
  label,
  errorMessage,
  onChange,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={value}
      label={label}
      helperText={<span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorMessage}</span>}
      onChange={onChange}
      margin="normal"
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

And also use `PropTypes` for better type checks.
With the `rest` approach you don't need to pass your props into others.
You have to simply use it like this

```
<DeliInput name='something' fullWidth />
```

and so on.

Comment: +1, I'd also remove `value`, `label` and `onChange` from the `DeliInput` props since you're just passing them on to the `TextField` unmodified anyway. The only prop this component needs is `errorMessage`

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer! I think this is a better approach for designing component. But my manager says it might be better to level up these three props and pass them directly. He says to add `jsDoc` for this component and it will be easier for other developers to use because they don't need to look up `Material UI` `TextField` documentation.